# how to determine if my script is run from extension or from website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My extension opens a new popup with :

```
chrome.windows.create({type:"panel", url: temp, width:pos.w,height:pos.h, top:pos.top, left:pos.left}, function (_win) {
        win = _win.id;
    });
```

and runs a JS script inside (that is also lunched from normal browser)

It opens a POPup window (normal popup windows) with external http page that contains the JS script.

How can I determine is the JS is run from extension or from normal browser ?
(without adding extra query parameters)

The extension version has no address bar and the browser has an address bar: so maybe a clumsy way would be to compare the outerHeight ?

Comment: The extension opens a POPup window (normal popup windows) with external http page that contains the JS script. The extension ONLY opens a popup window. So I need to know if this popup was opened from extension of from browser. Notice that popup window from extension has NO ADDRESS bar, thus his innerHeight is naturally bigger

Comment: And *where* exactly you need to determine that? In that remote page script or what?

Comment: the popup can either be opened from extension or from website. I would like my JS to have: alert("I come from extension") or alert("I come from website"). The JS is embedded into that page. The difference between extension popup and window popup is that window from extension has no address bar. I tried with referer or window.parent.location with no success.

Comment: What about [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)? If it's ok then either a duplicate of the question may be found or a new specific answer can be given.

Comment: yes: that's a solution I was thinking of. Not the simplest one since.. I need to re-submit the extension to google and firefox markets